# Status Script using JQuery/PHP dosent display Color on the other table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I used this script on Github and edited it a bit: https://gist.github.com/k0nsl/733955a3c3093832de49

Added a ping function over PHP which works fine.
I also wanted to split my Servers into 2 tables, so i have like the one for applications on the top and the servers itself on the bottom.

Here: http://pastebin.com/vqMievjA

It shows booth tables, it shows the status ico when its updating, the second table isnt red/green. Seems like JQuery isnt changing the color based on the status.

Any idea why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it the PHP way: http://pastebin.com/7dRyNGpk
Added type to the php array, the JQuery still takes care of all entries.

[image]